# React Router 1.0 - replace # and get rid of ?_k

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am getting **#** in the browser address bar plus **?_k=qy3joe** as querystring parameter e.g. http://localhost/#/login/?_k=qy3joe. It is not looking good in the production. How can i replace **#** with **my-app** and remove **_k=qy3joe**?

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;


var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
  <div>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
}
});

var Login = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (    
      <div className="large-3 medium-6 large-centered medium-centered columns"> 
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
      </div>

  ) }
});

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="login" component={Login}/>      
    </Route>
  </Router>
   ), document.getElementById('content'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to set up the router with something like:

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
```

This will give you URLs that look like http://www.example.com/my/path, and use the HTML5 history API to maintain location state, rather than a query key.

The usage of various histories is covered in the React Router guides at https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#createbrowserhistory.

Comment: That would be part of your routes, or the `basename` you specify with `useBasenames` per https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/v1.13.0/docs/BasenameSupport.md.

Comment: correct link to react router guide:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md